# Return placeholder data, if getSheetByName is null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a script that copies data from multiple sheets with a specific name and then consolidates it to a master sheet.

I am trying to figure out what to do when a sheet does not have that specific name. As of now, I have an if statement for this case that will just return the first sheet it finds in that spreadsheet. Ideally, I would like to return a single row with the value " name not found ".

I am not familiar with Google Script or working with spreadsheets so please point me to any documentation that would help.

```
function populateMasterTracker() {
 var trackerFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id"); 
 var trackerFiles = trackerFolder.getFiles();
 var combinedData = []; 
 var data;

//loop through files
while(trackerFiles.hasNext()){
  var file = trackerFiles.next();

  //object for each file
  var fileObject = {
    name: file.getName(),
    id: file.getId()
  }


  data = getDataFromSheet(fileObject.id,fileObject.name);
  combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);

}

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Master');

 ss.getRange(2,1,combinedData.length,8).setValues(combinedData);
}


function getDataFromSheet(id,name){
 var personalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
 var ss = personalSheet.getSheetByName('QC');

 if(!ss){
  //if qc not found
  Logger.log(name+ " not found")
  ss = personalSheet.getSheets()[0];
}

 var lastFilledRow = getLastPopulatedRow(ss.getRange('A:F').getValues());
 var range = ss.getRange('A2:H'+lastFilledRow);
 var data = range.getValues();

  Logger.log(data)

     return data
}
```

Comment: What do you want if you can't copy the data that you want from that spreadsheet.  We can't answer design questions.  It all depends upon what you want.  I might just make a note in the master that this id didn't have a sheet name `QC`

Comment: @Cooper Sorry if I wasn't clear. When the ID isnt found, I would want a single row to be pasted with the name of the file not found. The issue being I dont know how to create this row in the script and I think I would have to dynamically change the getRange method since this wouldn't fit the (2,1,length 8) parameters I am currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
function getDataFromSheet(id,name){
 var personalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
 var ss = personalSheet.getSheetByName('QC');
 if(!ss){
   return [[Utilities.formatString('FileName: %s ID: %s Has no sheet named %s',name,id,'QC')]]; //You may need to add 7 null columns so that all the data will be the same width.
 }else{

 var lastFilledRow = getLastPopulatedRow(ss.getRange('A:F').getValues());
 var range = ss.getRange('A2:H'+lastFilledRow);
 var data = range.getValues();
 return data
}
}
```